# Catch Response from URL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 URL,

1. http://comtrade.un.org/api/get?type=C&freq=M&px=HS&ps=201001&r=32&p=all&rg=all&cc=All&fmt=csv
2. http://comtrade.un.org/api/get/bulk/S/A/2010/0/EB02

I was capturing response from 2 URL, 1st URL will provide you downloadable CSV File and 2nd URL provides response in text (ex: {"Message":"Not found."})

I want to capture response from both the URL, 2nd one I can capture easily as its text based response, but 1st one is taking time as URL gives CSV file and object "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" download file & update the response.
Its taking huge time as some CSV file has more than 20MB data.

I have total 25K Links.

Now I want to capture like "CSV File Exist" for the link Like 1st one, means if csv exists then status should come as "CSV File Exist".

Could you please help me to achieve it. PFB procedure that I was using,

```
create procedure [dbo].[hit_url_adv](@url varchar(500),@fresults varchar(25) output,@ResponseText Varchar(8000) output)
as
begin

--sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1  
--GO   
--RECONFIGURE;  
--GO  
--sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1  
--GO   
--RECONFIGURE;  
--GO   
--sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1  
--GO   
--RECONFIGURE;  

declare @object int
declare @var varchar(1000)
declare @return int
declare @valid int

set @valid = 0;set @ResponseText=''

--create the XMLHTTP object
exec @return = sp_oacreate 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', @object output

if @return = 0
begin
    --Open the connection

    set @var='open("GET", "' + @url + '", false)'
    exec @return = sp_oamethod @object, @var

    if @return = 0
    begin
        --Send the request
        exec @return = sp_oamethod @object, 'send()'
        exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT   
        set @ResponseText=@ResponseText
    end

    if @return = 0
    begin
        declare @output int
        exec @return = sp_oamethod @object, 'status', @output output
        if @output = 200 set @valid = 1
    end
end

--destroy the object
exec sp_oadestroy @object

if @valid = 1 set @fresults='Success'
else set @fresults='Failure'
```

end

Comment: Why on earth you are doing this in `SQL Server`. Try in `Notepad` instead!

Comment: I have total 25000+ URL & I want to find how many URL having CSV file & others not.. How to do it in Notepad.

Comment: I have stored URL in table and updating status using another procedure.
declare i int,j int,URL varchar(max),urlHitStatus varchar(15),ResponseText Varchar(max)
set i=1
select j=max(i) from com_URL_2010
while(i<=j)
begin
 select URL=URL from com_URL_2010 where i=i
 exec hit_url_adv url, urlHitStatus OUTPUT, ResponseText OUTPUT
 update com_URL_2010 set urlHitStatus=urlHitStatus,ResponseText=ResponseText where i=i
 set i=i+1
end
select * from com_URL_2010

Comment: never mind, it was a joke. But you shold not really do this in SQL Server. It is not created for this type of problems.

Comment: I don't mind...it's ok, no issue.., I wanted to download data from 25K URL which has csv downloadable file, So I have tried using SQL, My procedure working fine & its updating. But, To update 500 links it took 1.30Hour, as it's downloading then updating the status. I have tried in javascript as well, but could not achieve it... Is there any way to do this... I have checked with friend, using .net can be done but there also same procedure and taking time to update...

Comment: Install xamp, write or search for php script that will check all urls and download data for you. Using SQL Server for this purpose is not ok.

Comment: ok thanks..will check it...